# Atribuir valor CSS dentro do JS

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Estou tentando atribuir um valor CSS via JS PURO.

Isso aqui funcionou :

```
$('a[title="Selecionar"]').css({ 'font-size':'0' });
```

Mas como que eu faço o **:after** do css nesse caso ??? , tipo :

```
$('a[title="Selecionar"]').css({ ':after' : {'font-size':'14px','content':'adicionar'} })
```

o **:after** não quer funcionar, pois não sei como fazer!

Comment: Olá Verônica, vc já tentou fazer uma busca rápida na internet para saber o que deseja, fiz uma pesquisa e no primeiro link que entrei já encontrei a resposta, por isso perguntas como a sua recebem votos negativos no site (não foi eu quem deu o negativo), a resposta para o que procura está aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: Sim, eu ja pesquisei.
Esse que você buscou, é o próprio CSS.

Eu quero atribuir CSS dentro de um código JS

Comment: Isso não dá certo porque o JS não tem acesso a pseudo-elementos. O JS manipula o DOM e pseudo-elementos não fazem parte do DOM (como próprio nome diz, "pseudo" é algo que não existe de verdade). Outra coisa é que na função .css você deve colocar um par de valores (propriedade, valor), e `:after` não é propriedade CSS. O que vc poderia fazer é adicionar um elemento (um `span`) com `.append()`.. o resultado seria o mesmo com `:after`.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não dá certo porque o JS não tem acesso a pseudo-elementos. O JS manipula o DOM e pseudo-elementos não fazem parte do DOM (como próprio nome diz, "pseudo" é algo que não existe de verdade).

Outra coisa é que na função `.css()` você deve colocar um par de valores `(propriedade, valor)`, e `:after` não é propriedade CSS.

O que você poderia fazer é adicionar um elemento (um `span`) com `.append()`. O resultado na prática seria o mesmo do `:after`, com a vantagem de poder manipular o `span` como quiser via JS.

Veja dois exemplos, um com `:after` no CSS e outro com `.append()` no JS:

## Com :after

```css
a[title="Selecionar"]:after{
   content: "olá";
   color: white;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" title="Selecionar">link</a>
```

## Com .append()

```js
$("a[title='Selecionar']").append(
  '<span style="color: white; background-color: red;">olá</span>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="Selecionar">link</a>
```